# Expected number of objects chosen by both A and B

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value, means

Suppose that A and B each randomly, and independently, choose 3 of 10 objects. Find the expected number of objects chosen by both A and B.

> solution: Let $X$ be the number of objects chosen by both A and B. For $1≤i≤10$, let $X_i=1$ if object $i$ is chosen by A and B, else $0$ otherwise
>
> Then $X=X_1+\ldots+X_{10}$.
>
> We find $E[X_i]=0⋅P(X_i=0)+1⋅P(X_i=1)=P(X_i=1)=9/100$.
>
> By the linearity of expectation, $E[X]=10⋅E[Xi]=0.9$

I understand this approach but I can't get the same answer by multiplying the probability of A and B having 1,2,3 objects in common by the values 1,2,3 and adding them, why is this approach concerned wrong ?
I assumed x is the number of objects chosen by both thus it takes the values 1,2,3

Comment: What do you get for the probabilities of 1, 2, or 3 objects in common?

Comment: The alternate approach you suggest can be correct (*though it is often considered far less elegant and is more prone to error or difficulty*).  The error must be in your calculations themselves, which you have not yet shared.  Show us your calculations and we'll tell you where your mistake is.

Comment: $\frac{1}{\binom{10}{3}*\binom{10}{3}}\left [ 1*\binom{10}{1}\binom{9}{2}\binom{9}{2} + 2*\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{1}\binom{8}{1} + 3*\binom{10}{3} \right ]$

I think I'm over counting somewhere here

Comment: @Saratci : disallow selection of the same "uncommon" item. $$\dfrac{\dbinom{10}{1}\dbinom{9}{2}\dbinom{7}{2}+2\dbinom{10}{2}\dbinom 81\dbinom 71+3\dbinom{10}3}{\dbinom{10}3^2}=\dfrac 9{10}$$

Comment: Yes you are right, Thanks !